# 15 day notification reminder sent out with an additional 3 day reminder sent after to user from due date

Tags: email-alert, recordtriggeredflow, scheduled-flow

I am not sure where to begin with this. But the use case is as follows:

Business would like to setup a 3 day reminder that would be sent out on the third day after a 15 day due date reminder is sent from the due date to a user.

I am not sure if this is possible to do in flows. I know you can set up separate due date reminder notifications say for 3 days or 15 days in a scheduled-trigger flow but they will not be associated with each other. Also, the business only wants to use one notification to be used for both 15 and 3 day due date reminder.

Can anyone provide some insight as to whether this can be done? If so, how would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: why not a reminder at +15 days and +18 days ?

Comment: @cropredy So are you saying have a reminder for 15 day sent prior to due date and then have another due date reminder set for 18 days(which is adding the 3 additional days). Would this be separate reminders created. Or is there a way to have these both one flow?

Comment: one record-triggered flow with 2 scheduled paths

Comment: @cropredy Thanks. Thats exactly what I did. I am testing currently. Waiting to see if it works. I will check this next week and will let you know if this worked. Thanks!

Comment: you don't have to actually wait until next week -- you can set the due Date to a value -17 days from today; the first path will execute in seconds, the second path will execute the next day

Comment: @cropredy Okay. I will try that. Thanks!

Comment: @cropredy Wanted to provide an update. So I decided to create a scheduled trigger flow, one for coming due, due today, and one for overdue notification.